# Как настроить правила безопасности firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, reactjs, firebase, firestore

Я пытаюсь написать приложение на react с использованием firestore. Вот только что мне ограничили доступ к моей дб. Изначально у меня были тестовые правила, потом мне пришло письмо с просьбой изменить правила безопасности. Я изменил, но дело в том, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы любой зашедший на сайт человек мог просматривать данные, а уже записывать/изменять их могли только зарегистрированные пользователи. Изменил я на такие:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Сейчас мне снова пришло письмо с предупреждением о том, что мои правил не безопасны. Я не понимаю, как мне нужно изменить их так, чтобы все пользователи могли просматривать контент из бд. Я, конечно, снова попробовал их изменить. Но, мне кажется, что это то же самое.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```